# Wallet to exchange transfer issue

Tags: transactions, transfer, exchanges

Please help me get my money back, I transferred a few matic tokens from a phantom wallet to an exchange, almost 17 hrs ago. after inquiring, the exchange tells me you used the Polygon network instead of ERC 20. How can I get it back?
any suggestions, please?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

yo, sadly i dont think there is a solution to your problem other than contacting the exchange support and hoping they are kind souls, they probably have access to the address, but will they bother helping you?

Comment: They denied, its gone

Comment: rip, sometimes in crypto u gotta learn the things the hard way, make sure not to do this mistake again, you arent the first time nor the last time it will happen!